# git clone Laravel and then it is not working

Tags: laravel, github

I am a verry new Leaner of Laravel framework. Laravel works properly on my desktop. I push my laravel project to github and then when i git clone the project, it is not working. Some pages show me run ***composer update***. after i run it, laravel shows errors of 500
Server Error. please help me. I use ubuntu

Comment: do you update .env file properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should update your .env file, because it is ignored by git from .gitignore. so you can copy paste .env.example to .env with this command:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

And make sure you have given permissions to storage and bootstrap folder.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

I hope it will help you. if not then please let me know. 
Thanks @AH.Pooladvand for the correction.

Comment: Giving full access to storage file is not a solution it's not a good practice, not safe, not even an answer

Comment: Can you please read the laravel documentation. @AH.Pooladvand https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#directory-configuration, please refer "Directory Permissions"

Comment: I've read it all. if there is a section that is saying that give `777` permission to storage file please let me know

Comment: `777` permission is a wrong thing to do and it causes security problems if you know how to config a server you will NEVER need to give `777` permission.

Comment: Thanks @AH.Pooladvand, I think that would be useful for me to get know, Can you please tell me what permissions should be here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204025/discussion-between-shailesh-matariya-and-ah-pooladvand).

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands in the directory where Laravel is installed:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R DIRECTORY_NAME
chmod -R o+w DIRECTORY_NAME/storage
```

Then clear the cache and dump the auto load:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: `cache:clear` is for the cache store ... what could they possibly have in their cache store and how does the cache store have anything to do with any of this?

Comment: He uploaded the code on the git server so it might be possible that his previous logs and caches are still there.he didn't ignore the storage folder in `.gitignore` file

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` command is used to clear cache. It will remove all the cache associated with the connection to the database. as I know this. I know that you know more then me correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: the cache store has nothing to do with the configuration cache, the route cache or the view cache

Answer (score 0):

By default there are some files in your `.gitignore` file which will not push into your github repository most important ones are `vendor` and `.env` files

- so first you should take a copy of your `.env.example` and make your `.env` file then set
- then run `php artisan key:generate` to create your application key
- and then set proper configuration of `.env` file like database and etc..
- if you are hosting your files in `/var/www/something` make sure `public` and `storage` directory has the proper permissions however hosting files as `root` user is strongly not recommended